# What are Punctuators in C++?

Tags: c++, punctuator

I don't seem to get my head around punctuators in C++. My college didn't even mention about it while teaching tokens, they referred to it as 'special symbols' and just skimmed through it. Are the two terms used interchangeably? How can I write about punctuators in some 80-100 words if it gets asked in my exam? I may want to know about the ways it interacts with the compiler, its difference from operators, or other things which could build a good short note on punctuators.

**Note:**

I have got [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/punctuators-cpp?view=vs-2019) after surfing the net for a quality answer. But that is a very short answer which is not what I'm looking for.

**Edit:**

Even a few points would do upon which I can build a short note.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited on [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Well people seem to be fine with it here, so maybe it is allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ standard document actually appears to not define what punctuator means, other than punctuators being a lexical token. Specifically:

> [gram.lex]
>
> ```
> token:
>   identifier
>   keyword
>   literal
>   operator
>   punctuator
> ```

Here is the definition from the C language:

> 6.4.6  Punctuators
>
> **Syntax**
>
> *punctuator*: one of
>
> ```
> [ ] ( ) { } . ->
> ++ -- & * + -  ~ !
> / % << >> < > <= >= == != ^ | && ||
> ? : ; ... = *=  /=  %=  > +=  -=  <<=  >>=  &= 
> ^= |= , # ## <: :> <% %> %: %:%:
> ```
>
> **Semantics**
>
> A  punctuator  is  a 
>   symbol  that  has  independent  syntactic  and  semantic 
>   significance. Depending  on  context,  it  may  specify  an  operation 
>   to  be  performed  (which  in  turn  may yield a value or a function
>   designator, produce a side effect, or some combination thereof) in 
>   which  case  it  is  known  as  an *operator* (other  forms  of  operator 
>   also  exist  in  some contexts).  An *operand* is an entity on which an
>   operator acts.

---

The grammar of C++ has similar list (quote from latest standard draft; the list includes the new operator <=> which will be in C++20):

> [lex.operators]
>
> *preprocessing-op-or-punc*: one of
>
> ```
>   {        }        [        ]        #        ##       (        )
>   <:       :>       <%       %>       %:       %:%:     ;        :        ...
>   new      delete   ?        ::       .        .*       ->       ->*      ~
>   !        +        -        *        /        %        ^        &        |
>   =        +=       -=       *=       /=       %=       ^=       &=       |=
>   ==       !=       <        >        <=       >=       <=>      &&       ||
>   <<       >>       <<=      >>=      ++       --       ,
>   and      or       xor      not      bitand   bitor    compl     and_eq  
>   or_eq    xor_eq   not_eq
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I see that even the Standard hasn't defined it well enough, hence you have also answered why this thing is so less popular and not taught properly! Upvoted.

Comment: Although you didn't answer if those two terms could be used interchangeably

Comment: @ArdentCoder "Special symbol" is a way to describe punctuators. "Special symbol" is not a strictly defined term and its meaning can vary depending on context. For example, you could consider $ to be a special symbol, but it is not a punctuator in C++.

Comment: Oh, the counterexample of $ seems very good. Thanks for all the valuable points :)